# "capability of doing" or "capability to do"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I would like ask if there is any semantic difference between the following sentences:

> What makes us different from other animal families is that we have a
>   complicated brain that has the  capability **of creating** new
>   technologies.
>
> What makes us different from other animal families is that we have a
>   complicated brain that has the capability  **to create** new technologies.

---

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38964/how-to-use-to-v-ing -

Comment: @mplungjan I see your point. However, not every word which are followed by "to" may be gerund.

Comment: No, there is no difference between these.  "Capability of creating" sounds wrong to me -- but language evolves and we don't always evolve with it.  [Ngram suggests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=capability+of+creating%2Ccapability+to+create&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) it's become quite popular, recently.

Comment: @Andrew can I ask  why does it sound wrong? Is it because of the verb " create" or the sentence itself or the usage of " of + ing" sounds wrong than " to +infinitive " form  although it is grammatically correct according to dictionaries?

Comment: @Mrt Grammaticality is not the same as idiomaticity. There are grammatical phrases or structures that may sound more or less idiomatic. In English, sometimes the shorter the better. Personally, I don't see much difference between "capability to do sth" and "capability of doing sth", but I'm not a native speaker and we have to trust those who are. I do find, however, that "ability to do sth" is more idiomatic than "ability of doing sth", perhaps because one says "be able to do sth". With "of" being the preposition that comes after the adjective "capable", "capability of doing sth" is reasonable

Comment: You may want to check this related thread: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4439/is-capable-vs-has-capability